# @JsonRawValue ignored in JAX-RS 2.0 server with Jackson

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, marshalling

I've followed the standard method to have Jackson be the JSON provider for my JAX-RS 2.0 app adding

```
classes.add(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
```

in the getClasses method of the ws.rs.Application class

I have some classes with a couple of fields annotated with @JsonRawValue as they have JSON inside which I don't want to escape when the class is marshalled (I don't want "JSON inside JSON")

Is there any alternative standard way to make sure that a JAX-RS 2.0 application uses Jackson?

(I am using Websphere Liberty 16.0.0.3)

Edit to add requested clarification:

- I use @JsonRawValue in the getter method of a property.
- My intention is to have a property no to be escaped if it already has JSON content. For example:

  String myJSONvalue = "{\"var\":\"value\"}";

Without @JsonRawValue, myJSONvalue will be serialised as JSON, so it will be escaped, to have a JSON String inside a JSON content. I want to prevent this behaviour. I think that is precisely what the tag is intended for... to have a value be considered as JSON Raw Value. But even including the annotation, the value is escaped and not considered as raw. I think I have a problem the way I am registering Jackson Mapper with specific features enabled to make this behaviour be considered in JAX-RS 2.0 application.

Comment: Can you please show how you are using `@JsonRawValue`? What's the expected result? What is happening? Show a bit of code.